# How can I display Template Variables in the Articles Overview in MODX?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

In my "Articles" resource in the manager I have a table that shows all my posts. There I see: publish date/Post Title/Author/Comments and Tags.

I wish to have also a specific template variable to be displayed into this table.

Do you know, if there is a way to do that?

(I am happy for every hint, because "Articles" doesn't offer categories,so I need to create this option by template variables.)

By the way, do you know why there is no active forum for ModX questions? It is very difficult to get feedback or help for this content management system.

Comment: http://forums.modx.com/

Comment: @SeanKimball Thank you, but they do not answer questions as good as stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

First of all, articles is discontinued. I just setup a blog and I used collections for it.

Next: forums.modx.com is a good place, twitter is fast if you add the #MODX hashtag to your question. Best option: Link on twitter to your question in MODX forums :)

Now on your main question: there is no option in articles to modify the view in the backend. If you use collections, it's easy and even described in the official docs: https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/collections

As you can see on the image, you can have images (and all kind of TVs) in the overview. [Collections can display all kind of TVs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVtZF.png)

As Articles and Collections is just another way to present resources inside the backend, it's 100% compatible. So you can change from articles to collections quite easily.